# VolleyError Unexpected response code 406 with REST GET request

Tags: java, android, rest, get, android-volley

I am trying to create the Android version of a curl GET request. Works great in terminal, but fails in the app.

The curl request (urls are not real):

```
curl -d '{"detail": "Y"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET -H "Auth-Token:longstringhereforauthtoken" https://api.myendpoint.com/REST/GSLB/zone-to-get-records-from.com/fqdn-of-domain.com/
```

It gives back what I need without any issue.

Well, now I want to use that request in a Volley request in Android, however, I am getting back:

`Unexpected response code 406 for https://api.myendpoint.com/REST/GSLB/zone-to-get-records-from.com/fqdn-of-domain.com/`

The code where I'm attempting the request is as follows (will show relevant variables that are set beforehand):

```
private String url;
private String request;
private String searchRequest;

String selected = getIntent().getStringExtra("node");
String token = getIntent().getStringExtra("token");

url = getResources().getString(R.string.api_url);
request = url + "/Session/";
searchRequest = url + "/GSLB/"+selected+"/"+selected+"/";


ProgressDialog searchDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        searchDialog.setMessage("Getting zone info...");
                        searchDialog.show();

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            object.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            object.put("Auth-Token", token);
                            object.put("detail", "Y");
                        } catch(JSONException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "Selected "+icon+", Token: "+token);
                        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, searchRequest, object,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        searchDialog.dismiss();
                                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                searchDialog.dismiss();
                                if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Request to "+searchRequest+" FAILED...");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        RequestQueue searchRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                        searchRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

That is when I receive the error:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 406 for https://api.myendpoint.com/REST/GSLB/zone-to-get-records-from.com/fqdn-of-domain.com/
```

Before this activity, I have a LoginActivity that does a similar request, which is where the token comes from in the GET request. It sends credentials and received the Auth-Token. This one works, so I am unsure of why the previous snippet is failing.

The Login request:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
    object.put("user_name", usernameEditText.getText().toString());
    object.put("customer_name", customernameEditText.getText().toString());
    object.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
    object.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
} catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, request, object,
  new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         if(response != null) {
            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(response));
            String token = null;
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
               token = response.getJSONObject("data").getString("token");
               Log.d("JSON", token);
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                  Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SelectActivity.class);
                  loginIntent.putExtra("token", token);
                  LoginActivity.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
         } else {
            Toast nullToast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Credentials\nPlease try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            nullToast.show();
            usernameEditText.getText().clear();
            customernameEditText.getText().clear();
            passwordEditText.getText().clear();
           }

    }
```

}

I have done these requests in both PHP and cURL, but can't seem to understand why it's failing with Android. I feel like my syntax is correct, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: 406 http error code stays for "not acceptable". This means that your request has an incorrect header

Comment: That was what I needed! I will edit my question to show how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

406 http error code stays for "**not acceptable**". This means that your request has an incorrect header. I believe that `JsonObjectRequest` doesn't manage headers, but the request body.
In order to work on request header you need to override the getHeaders() method from VolleyRequest class, something like:

```kotlin
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  params.put("Auth-Token", token);
  params.put("detail", "Y");

  return params;
}
```

Comment: You explained why getHeaders() is necessary. I will accept your answer. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: My pleasure, anytime 

Answer (score 1):

The clue was in the request response error code (406). Instead of this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
  object.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  object.put("Auth-Token", token);
  object.put("detail", "Y");
 } catch(JSONException e) {
     Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
   }
```

I used the `getHeaders()` method to send my headers, like so:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  params.put("Auth-Token", token);
  params.put("detail", "Y");

  return params;
}
```

Though I do not understand why my `object.put()` does not work (It was in any tutorials I viewed, so I need to research more), this was what fixed it. I'm now getting my response successfully.